# Use laravel elixir to transpile es6 that uses "import" statements

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-elixir

Trying to use laravel-elixir to transpile some code that was working fine with jspm, but with the following snippets, the end result is I get an error in the browser complaining about jQuery not being loaded (`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`). I'm told that its because browserify needs to run the babelify transform (or run in the babelify transform mode?), not sure exactly what that means, obvious first time experience with these tools.

app.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import PBNumberSet from './class/PBNumberSet';

var primary = new PBNumberSet('#primary_pbset');
```

gulpfile

```
gulp.task('default', () => {
    var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

    elixir(function(mix) {
        mix.sass('app.scss')
            .browserify([
                'app.js'
            ], 'public/js/app.js')
            .version([
                'css/app.css',
                'js/app.js'
            ]);
    });
});
```

The generated file:

Comment: try change your browserify to babel

Comment: @SSuhat Yep done that, I get a different error then

Comment: if below answer helps you, click on the gray button on the left side of it (below points)

Answer (score 1):

If you use $ in PBNumberSet.js, you should import $ in that file, not in app.js.

I suppose it causes error.

You should still use browserify().